# Expectation over a list with nested-mapped expressions

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, probability-or-statistics, map

I need expected values of a list where the random variable to take expectations over should be an input into expressions defined earlier. I suspect Set[] and SetDelayed[] tripped me. (Or Map and Table?)

I hope the intention is reasonably clear from the code: I am interested in expressions of six numbers in [0,1] where I suspect (model) that they have been measured with error (errors being independent and uniform here, but answers truncated to lie in the meaningful range anyway). I don't get the solution I expect, only an expression substituted into.

Input:

```
AList = {a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6}
answers := (Min[1,Max[# ,0]])& /@ (AList+errors)
dlist ={answers[[5]],answers[[6]],answers[[3]]/answers[[1]],answers[[4]]/answers[[2]]} 
deltasbetas = Expectation[dlist,errors\[Distributed]Table[UniformDistribution[],{6}]]
```

(note that errors are defined within Expectation, as I think it should be)
Output:

```
{Min[1,Max[0,0.8 +UniformDistribution[{0,1}]]],Min[1,Max[0,0.7 +UniformDistribution[{0,1}]]],Min[1,Max[0,0.5 +UniformDistribution[{0,1}]]]/Min[1,Max[0,0.8 +UniformDistribution[{0,1}]]],Min[1,Max[0,0.4 +UniformDistribution[{0,1}]]]/Min[1,Max[0,0.7 +UniformDistribution[{0,1}]]]}
```

Comment: what are `AList` and `errors`?

Comment: @R.M: My mistake, I confused names. I also cleared up where errors should be coming from.

Comment: It looks like Mathematica thinks errors is a scalar, because its Table-definition comes too late. Though it still substitutes it, so why doesn't it calculate the expectation?

Comment: I can put the "tabling" within `UniformDistribution` to make it multivariate, which is more of my intention, but then it is not even substituted into `errors`, as it is not seen to be a list.

Comment: I think you need to use [`TransformedDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/TransformedDistribution.html) ... but how?:)

Comment: @kguler: I have hopes that this would work if only `errors` were kept as a list until it was properly filled in with the distribution by `Expectation`. Is there a way to do that? To restrict `errors` to be a list?

Comment: I think maybe you have to explicitly use something like `{e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6} \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{{0,1},{0,1},{0,1},{0,1},{0,1},{0,1}}]` instead of just one `errors` variable.

Comment: @Silvia: Nice! This solves it! It is just a bit disappointing that once I tried to be fancy with Mathematica and use the higher-level contracts it is proud of, it did not work. Maybe because I got it wrong, of course. (Btw, even this simple stats calculation is surprisingly slow, hm.)

Comment: The grammar comes from doc of `Expectation`. I think the essential problem is that a `Table` is not a `Distribution`, so it should not be after `\[Distributed]`.

Comment: `errors=Array[er,6]`  before you use `errors`; and then use `errors \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[Table[{0, 1}, {6}]` instead of `errors \[Distributed] Table...`.

Comment: @kguler: Thanks! Two questions: So it's no problem that `er` will go undefined? And: I think the summation of lists work fine without threading. What am I missing about `Thread`?

Comment: Also, please let me know if you know how to `Manipulate` the results in terms of `underlying`. Thanks!

Comment: @László, pls ignore the `Thread` comment. Regarding `er` going undefined, `errors=Array[er,{6}]` defines errors as a list with 6 elements with names `er[1]` thru `er[6]`. So,  you can use the symbol `errors` instead of `{e1,e2,...,e6}`.

Comment: @kguler: Thanks. And I will ask the `Manipulate` question separately.

Comment: @kguler: On your analytic solution below: if I feed in a list into `a` (in the solution), I don't get back numerical answers.

Comment: If I use `deltasbetas /. Thread[aList -> underlying]` I get `{0.98, 0.955, 0.895251, 0.866473}`; using `deltasbetas[[1]] /. a[5] -> .8` you get `0.98`. (BTW, these numbers are for standard uniform.) If you change the distribution parameters form `{0,1}` to `{0, 0.1}` you get the same numbers as in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

If there is no way to use a "list variable" for the random vector, an explicit list of scalars can be filled in with the right distribution, thanks to @Silvia:

```
underlying := {0.8, 0.7, 0.5, 0.4, 0.8, 0.7}
answers := (Min[1, Max[# , 0]]) & /@ (underlying + {e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6})
dlist := {answers[[5]], answers[[6]], answers[[3]]/answers[[1]], answers[[4]]/answers[[2]]} 
deltasbetas = Expectation[dlist,
         {e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6} \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[Table[{0, 0.1}, {6}]]]

{0.85, 0.75, 0.647807, 0.600891}
```

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Using assumptions on the `aList`, namely, that all `a[i]`s are in the unit interval, we get symbolic results for `Expectation`:

```
aList = Array[a, {6}];
errors = Array[er, 6];
answers = (Min[1, Max[#, 0]]) & /@ (aList + errors);
dlist = {answers[[5]], answers[[6]], answers[[3]]/answers[[1]], answers[[4]]/answers[[2]]};
deltasbetas = Expectation[dlist, 
errors \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[Table[{0, 1}, {6}]], 
Assumptions -> {And @@ Table[0 < a[i] <= 1, {i, 6}]}]
```

we get

[image]

EDIT 1: For `UniformDistribution[0,1/10]`

```
 Expectation[dlist,  errors \[Distributed] 
 UniformDistribution[Table[{0, 1/10}, {6}]], Assumptions -> {And @@ Table[0 < a[i] <= 1, {i, 6}]}]
```

we get

[image]

Evaluating at `underlying`:

```
 % /. Thread[aList -> underlying]
```

we get

```
{0.85, 0.75, 0.647807, 0.600891}
```

EDIT 2: Alternative specifications of the joint distribution under `Expectation`:

```
 Expectation[dlist, errors \[Distributed] 
 ProductDistribution[Table[UniformDistribution[], {6}]], 
 Assumptions -> {And @@ Table[0 < a[i] <= 1, {i, 6}]}]
```

give the same result.

So does

```
 trdist = TransformedDistribution[dlist, 
 errors \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[Table[{0, 1}, {6}]]];
 Expectation[z, z \[Distributed] trdist, 
 Assumptions -> {And @@ Table[0 < a[i] <= 1, {i, 6}]}]
```

Comment: Nice, thank you! So I can `Manipulate` the result be giving it values of `aList` (or `a`?) And still `Plot` the resulting list in terms of the range of the error distribution (simply numerically 1 in the example)?

Comment: Only 40 more to 10k (which you should reach today). Congrats in advance! :)

Comment: @R.M thank you!!